# refresh page after submit with tabs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I want to have refresh the page after save. I am using tabs, like this:

```
   <div id="tabs-2">

        @using (Html.BeginForm("EditPhotos", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <h4>Photos</h4>
                <hr />

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)


                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayItem)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayItem)

                </div>

                <div id="upload-choices">
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image)

                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-row">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br />

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">

                        <tr>
                            <th><img width="200" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Account", new { id =  Model.Id })"></th>


                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <input type="file" name="file" class="filestyle" data-buttontext="Find file">



                <br />
                <div class="progress progress-striped">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">0%</div>
                </div>

                <div id="status"></div>


                <br />

                @*@Html.ActionLink("Upload photos", "Upload")*@
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="submit" value="Save"  accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg" class="btn btn-default pull-left" />

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        }

        <br /><br />
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this is the JQuery:

```
$("form").ajaxForm({



                    beforeSend: function () {

                        status.empty();
                        var percentVal = '0%';
                        bar.width(percentVal)
                        percent.html(percentVal);
                    },
                    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                        bar.width(percentVal)
                        percent.html(percentVal);
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        var percentVal = '100%';
                        bar.width(percentVal)
                        percent.html(percentVal);
                    },
                    complete: function (xhr) {
                        status.html(xhr.responseText);
                    }
               // });
            });
```

and this is my controller action method:

```
[HttpPost]
        //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditPhotos(UserProfile userprofile, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            if (file != null)
            {


                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                ModelState.Clear();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
                UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));

                // Update fields
                user.Image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(user.Image, 0, file.ContentLength);
                user.ImageMimeType = file.ContentType;

                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();

              //  return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account")+ "#tabs-2");

            }

            return RedirectToAction(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-2");


        }
```

but after uploading(save) I get this error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /Account/Account/Edit#tabs-2
```

so how to improve the RedirectAction with the tabs?

Thank you

ok, I have it now like this:

```
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    //    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);
    window.location.hash;
   // $("#tab-2").show();
```

but after refresh, it jumps to the first tab and not tabs-2(so current tab)

like this:

```
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    //    $(document).on("click", ".btn", function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", window.location.hash);
    window.location.hash;
    $("a[href=tabs-2]").trigger("click");
```

oke, I tried like this:

$("#tabs").tabs(
        {

```
        select: function(event, ui) {
            document.getElementById("tabs-2").value = ui.index;
        },
        selected: document.getElementById("tabs-2").value
    });
```

but still goes to first tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying as below,

```
return RedirectToAction(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#/tabs-2");
```

Even if you get this working, not sure the tab will be selected. Since the tabs will only be selected based on events not on the query string. So it is preferred to create a new query string as 'tab' or 'active' or as you like and pass the value of active tab.

```
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", routeValues: new { controller = "Account", activetab = "tabs-2" });
```

Then using jquery, on document load you may trigger the click event for the tab by appropriate selector by yourself.

Try as,

```
$("a[href='#tabs-2']").trigger("click");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the problem is that:   return Redirect(Url.Action("Edit", "Account") + "#tabs-2"); doestn work, because no page refresh, only after f5 the page refreshed

Comment: still goes to first tab

Comment: @NielsSavant Sorry I left to give "'" for the href attribute values, please try including that. Also check whether the trigger event is successful with no js errors. And ensure that the 'tabs-2' is the correct href value for the hyperlink.

Comment: Hi Venkat, can you post the complete jquery code so your code with mine. then I can test it Thank you

Comment: @NielsSavant Just see my updated answer which will be enough.

Comment: what do you mean with: Sorry I left to give "'" for the href attribute values, please try including that

Comment: @NielsSavant I missed out to include the value in quotes for the href attribute of the hyperlink in the selector which should be as, $("a[href='#tabs-2']").trigger("click");